# Custom converter for System.Text.Json when working with generics

Tags: c#, system.text.json

I have a class that contains a generic (`object`) that could either be populated with a `string`, `int`, `bool`, or another instance of the same class.  Previously, when using Newtonsoft.Json, I had a custom converter that would determine how to deserialize based on whether the `JToken.Type` was `JTokenType.Object` (detecting that the value was likely another instance of the same class).

With `System.Text.Json` and the `JsonConverter`, I don't see a way to do this.  It appears I have to perform a `.Read()` which gives the next token (`StartObject`, `EndObject`, `StartArray`, ... `String`, etc).

I see facilities to `reader.GetString()` to pull the value, (same with `.GetInt32()` and others), but no way to *read the next object*.  i.e. if I determine that the value for a property is another instance of the same class, I want to read that object in its entirety and assign it to that property.

My converter for Newtonsoft.Json is below (note that it recursively calls the deserialization method when it encounters an instance of the same class within either the `Left` or `Right` property):

```
public class ExpressionConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return (objectType == typeof(Expression));
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        Expression ret = new Expression();
        JObject jo = JObject.Load(reader);
        if (jo["Left"] != null)
        {
            JToken leftToken = jo["Left"];
            if (leftToken.Type == JTokenType.Object)
            {
                ret.Left = SerializationHelper.DeserializeJson<Expression>(leftToken.ToString());
            }
            else if (leftToken.Type == JTokenType.Array)
            {
                ret.Left = leftToken.ToObject<List<object>>();
            }
            else
            {
                ret.Left = leftToken.ToObject<string>();
            }
        }

        ret.Operator = (OperatorEnum)(Enum.Parse(typeof(OperatorEnum), jo["Operator"].ToString()));

        if (jo["Right"] != null)
        {
            JToken rightToken = jo["Right"];
            if (rightToken.Type == JTokenType.Object)
            {
                ret.Right = SerializationHelper.DeserializeJson<Expression>(rightToken.ToString());
            }
            else if (rightToken.Type == JTokenType.Array)
            {
                ret.Right = rightToken.ToObject<List<object>>();
            }
            else
            {
                ret.Right = rightToken.ToObject<string>();
            }
        }

        return ret;
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

My question is: can I read out the entire object (some series of tokens) to assign to either the `Left` or `Right` property?

EDIT: more context.  The `Expression` class is:

```
public class Expression
{
  public object Left { get; set; } = null;
  public OperatorEnum Operator { get; set; } = OperatorEnum.Equals;
  public object Right { get; set; } = null;
}
```

and the input JSON could look like something as easy as:

```
{
  "Left": "Amount",
  "Operator": "GreaterThan",
  "Right": 100.00
}
```

or complex/nested like:

```
{
  "Left": {
    "Left": {
      "Left": "Amount",
      "Operator": "GreaterThan",
      "Right": 100.00
    },
    "Operator": "And",
    "Right": {
      "Left": "NameOnCard",
      "Operator": "Contains",
      "Right": "Smith"
    }
  },
  "Operator": "And",
  "Right": {
    "Left": {
      "Left": "Brand",
      "Operator": "Equals",
      "Right": "Visa"
    },
    "Operator": "Or",
    "Right": {
      "Left": "Brand",
      "Operator": "Equals",
      "Right": "Mastercard"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Newtonsoft.Json, it appears you can recursively call `JsonSerializer.Deserialize` and pass the `ref Utf8JsonReader` along with the custom serializer as parameters.

Here is the code from within the custom serializer:

```
if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.StartObject)
{
    ret.Right = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Expression>(ref reader, new JsonSerializerOptions
    {
        DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull,
        Converters = { new JsonStringEnumConverter(), new ExpressionConverter() },
    });
}
```

The deserializer will pick up after where the recursion left off.  Worked like a charm.